# Redmine files upload error

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger, redmine

I have a problem with files upload in Redmine. Error is: 500 internal server error.
In logs I have no information ( apache log & production.log ).

What I have tried:

1. Change rights on /usr/share/redmine/files to 777 ( no result )
2. Change rights on /usr/share/redmine to 777 ( no result )
3. Checked owner for /usr/share/redmine ( it is admin )
4. Checked PassengerDefaultUser ( it is admin )

Result of "ps -ef | grep Passenger | grep -v grep" command:

```
root     27534 26624  0 17:23 ?        00:00:00 PassengerWatchdog
admin    27537 27534  0 17:23 ?        00:00:01 PassengerHelperAgent
nobody   27543 27534  0 17:23 ?        00:00:00 PassengerLoggingAgent
admin    27588     1  0 17:23 ?        00:00:04 Passenger RackApp: /usr/share/redmine
```

System: Apache 2.4, Passenger Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.53, Redmine 2.5.2.stable

I tried all that I can, but have no result. :-(